# Extending system(root) partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

I want to add unallocated space
to my root partition (on the left), however the swap partition and my main partition are in the way,
I'm unsure of what to do next, do I move the unallocated space to the left of my main partition, delete the swap partition, resize root partition and then recreate the swap partition?

I have windows installed on a separate ssd (nvme)

[image]

Appreciate any help!
Elam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Hi, no sadly it doesnt, i cant simply resize it because of the other partitions, and im unsure if moving my main partition is ok or will cause a problem

Comment: You are on the right track. First back up your files. Second boot from the Ubuntu installation USB in the **Try Ubuntu** mode. Third, disable swap by right clicking on the swap partition in the bottom part of the Gparted window and clicking on **Swapoff**. Fourth you move the home partition to the right. Fifth, you move the swap partition to the right. Sixth, you expand the root partition.

Comment: Thank you! if I turn the swap back on after, will it just work or do i have to do something else?

Comment: It should work, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!